# Abbreviations in vim

Tags: neovim

I usually open Neovim with the command `nvim`, but when I do this the abbreviations do not work. But it works when I open editor with a file name like this: `nvim /containers/index.js`

This is my abbreviation: `iabbrev <buffer> clg@ console.log();<Left><Left>`

Comment: I just realized that if I enter this command :source [the path to my vimrc file] it works, what is weird is the other plugins and things are working correctly so I am sure the vimrc file is working ok

Comment: Neovim doesn't use `~/.vimrc`. Configuration of Neovim goes into `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.nvim` (if you haven't set XDG variables, then it's  `~/.config/nvim/init.nvim` by default)

Comment: Also, do you know what does `<buffer>` mean here?

Comment: Yeah you are right, I do use init.vim it was my mistake, I am not sure about what <buffer> means there but that is what I read about how to create abbreviations but I am not sure why it does not work when I open nvim in a directory but works when I open directly a file @Jorengarenar thanks for your help.